# Continuity on the boundary of mixed elliptic problems

Tags: elliptic-pde

Let $B$ the interior of a Polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose  $a^{ij}  \in C^\infty (\overline{B})$ , $a^{ij}(x)y_i y_j \geq \lambda |y|^2$ $\forall x\in B, \ \ y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Set $\Gamma := \cup _i \Gamma _i $, where $\Gamma _i$ is the interior of a face of $\overline{B}$. Suppose also that  $c\in L^q (B)$,   $c_1 \in L^{q_1} (\partial B -\overline{\Gamma})$  for same  $q$, $q_1 > n-1$. Consider the following problem

\begin{equation}
     \left\{
           \begin{array}{rl}
        -(a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j} + c u  = f    & \mbox{on} \ B\\
         u=g & \mathrm{in\ } \Gamma\\
         a^{ij}u_{x_i} \nu _j +  c_1u=h   & \mathrm{in\ } \partial B - \overline{\Gamma} \ \  \ \ (\nu \ \ \mbox{is a outward-pointing vector to } \  B)
           \end{array}
         \right.
   \end{equation}

If $f\in C(B)\cap L^\infty (B) $ and  $g,h \in C(\overline{B})$ then a solution of the mixed problem above is continous on $\overline{B}$ ?? Please, I would very much like references of papers or books that answer this question.